# How to select single rows from a dataframe, calculate cumulative return and plot it in single figure

Tags: python

I have a dataframe (portbase) that contains multiple signals (signalname) and their returns.

[image: Screenshot of dataframe]

I want to subset every single, calculate the cumulative return and then plot them in a single figure.
I have done it step by step with on single as an example:

```
ChInvIA = portbase[portbase['signalname'] == 'ChInvIA']
cum_perf_ChInvIA = ChInvIA['return'].cumsum() + 100
cum_perf_ChInvIA.plot()
plt.show()
```

With multiple signals this would take me way too long and therefore i've tries to loop over my dataframe.

```
for i in signals:
    i = portbase[portbase['signalname'] == 'i']
    cum_perf_i = i['return'].cumsum() + 100
    cum_perf_i.plot()
    plt.show()
```

It doesn't work and i've tried to find a solution.

Comment: You have a typo in your code... it should be `i = portbase[portbase['signalname'] == i]` withoug the single quotations around `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling both the looping variable and a variable in the loop by the name `i`, and comparing `signalname` to a string containing i (`'i'`) instead of the variable itself. You should do something like this instead:

```
for i in signals:
    signal_i = portbase[portbase['signalname'] == i]
    cum_perf_i = signal_i['return'].cumsum() + 100
    cum_perf_i.plot()
    plt.show()
```

To have all the plots in the same figure, you should use matplotlib's [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) function:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(signals))
for ind, i in enumerate(signals):
    signal_i = portbase[portbase['signalname'] == i]
    cum_perf_i = signal_i['return'].cumsum() + 100
    cum_perf_i.plot(ax=ax[ind])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Perfect! It's working now. Could you also tell me how i could plot all the graphs in one figure? Right now i have multiple figures..

Comment: Works perfectly! One last question: is there a way to add a legend for each signal? If i use plt.legend(), then my legend equals 'return' and not the name of the signal...

Comment: `ax[ind].legend()` might do what you need - it will add a legend for each plot. Btw, you can pass a list to the `legend` function (both to `plt.legend` and `ax.legend`). The values in the list will be displayed in the legend.